# Changing IPEndpoint of ChannelFactory in WCF connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Is it possible to change the outgoing ip address of client to WCF Service using ServicePoint?

```
var localIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.113");
ServicePoint servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(oDataSource.wcfURL));
servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate =
                (sp, rm, retryCount) =>
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(retryCount);
                    return new IPEndPoint(localIpAddress, 80);
                };

DuplexChannelFactory<IBSPubSubService> oChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IBSPubSubService>(new InstanceContext(this), oBinding, oEndpoint);
oPubSubClient = oChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
oPubSubClient.Faulted += new EventHandler(WcfFaultedListener);
oPubSubClient.Opened += new EventHandler(WcfOpenListener);
```

I tried using the code above but does not work. Seems like BindIPEndpointDelegate enters endless loop once oChannelFactory.CreateChannel() is called.

Answer (score 0):

It tries to bind unsuccessfully until *int.MaxValue*.

> If you are not able to choose the local Endpoint, just return null and an endpoint is automatically chosen for you.

Here's [a link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malarch/2005/09/13/servicepoint-bindipendpointdelegate/)